# How could I fetch multiple Google drive API filess for mail ids google drive API client library in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to populate multiple Google drive files for different file mail ids using google drive API client library in c#. Suppose I have file ids like 1hfgh,2trter,3ewrwer...

When I will pass these file ids the drive files should populated. I have written the file population code like below:

```
FilesResource.ListRequest list = service.Files.List();
                list.MaxResults = 10;
                if (search != null)
                {
                    list.Q = search;
                }
 FileList filesFeed = list.Execute();
```

I'm using Google.Apis.Drive.v2
If anyone has any idea please share.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for the q method of files.list also called [files search](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)

You can search or filter files with the files.list method of the Drive API. These methods accept the q parameter which is a search query combining one or more search clauses. Each search clause is made up of three parts.

> Field
>  Attribute of the file that is searched, e.g., the attribute
>   name of the file.
>  Operator
>  Test that is performed on the data
>   to provide a match, e.g., contains.
>  Value
>  The content of the
>   attribute that is tested, e.g. the name of the file My cool
>   document.
>  Combine clauses with the conjunctions and or or, and
>   negate the query with not.

Anwser: you cant search on file ids only fields like name.  Option use file.get more then once and add them to a fileList

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It helped me to solve the issue in other way.